# Sum of two basis is again basis

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $\{a_1, a_2,...,a_n\}$ and $\{b_1,b_2,...,b_n\}$ be two bases of $\Bbb R^n$. Let P be square matrix of order $n$ with real entries such that $Pa_i=b_i, i=1,2..,n$. Suppose that every eigenvalue of P is either $-1$ or $1$. Let $Q=I+2P$. Then which of the fallowing is true?

1) $\{a_i+2b_i | i=1,2,...,n\}$ is also a basis of $\Bbb R^n$.

2) Q is invertible

I got that 2) is true. but not getting the 1)

I know that, I have to show that $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \alpha _i(a_i+2b_i)=0$ when all constants $\alpha _i, i=1,2,...,n$ It seems difficult for me to show this. I write all $b_1,b_2,...,b_n$ as linear combination of $a_1,a_2,...,a_n$ and putted the values in the sum. which gives more difficult expression to give all constants are zero. Please help me. Thank you

Comment: What if $b_i = -a_i / 2$?

Comment: then set will contain a zero vector, and it will become linearly dependent

Comment: could that be a basis?

Comment: Nice counter example.

Comment: Nopz, It will not be a basis. wait sir i'm editing my question.

Comment: @user251257 Now see and tell me the right way to handle this option

Comment: The image of a basis under an isomorphism is a basis again

Comment: Explain more.. How this statement works here? P and Q both are invertible so both are isomorphism but unable to connect all these chains.

Comment: @user251257 ,,,,

Comment: @aryan $a_i + 2b_i = Qa_i$, $Q$ is an isomorphism, $a_1,\dotsc,a_n$ is basis.

Answer (score 2):

As you can consider $Q$ as an injective operator which preserve linear independence and $Q_{ai} =I_{ai} + 2P_{ai}=ai+2bi$.

Comment: Welcome on the MathSE! This site supports $\latex$. :-) Just write `$Q_{ai}$` and you get $Q_{ai}$. I am not sure if I latexized your post correctly, feel free to make it ready. :-) Good luck here!